# KSE and Shannon entropy

Tags: soft-question, dynamical-systems, information-theory

Is there a theoretical connection between Kolmogorov-Sinai and Shannon entropies? What is it?

Comment: Which part of your question is not covered [there](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Entropy#Entropy_in_mathematics)?

Comment: Cross reference: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645841/connection-between-boltzmann-entropy-and-kolmogorov-entropy/693264 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527384/what-is-the-connectivity-between-boltzmanns-entropy-expression-and-shannons-en/527812